# How to change label text through for loop?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

I'm have this code that creates a panel with nine buttons and a label, when a button is clicked the label changes so that it says witch number is clicked.

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to replace the if function in actionPerformed with a for loop so it does the same thing?

This is the code I have:

```
package zadatak;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class forPetlja {

    private JFrame mojOkvir;
    private JPanel p1, p2;
    private JLabel txtLabela;

    public forPetlja() {
        pripremiGUI();
    }

    private void pripremiGUI() {
        //okvir
        mojOkvir = new JFrame("Primena 2 panela");
        mojOkvir.setSize(400, 250);
        mojOkvir.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mojOkvir.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //paneli
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JButton"));
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JLabel i Panel p1"));
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //labela
        txtLabela = new JLabel("Prikazi koje je dugme kliknuto.");
    }

    private void prikaziGUI() {
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                    txtLabela.setText("Kliknut je broj " + e.getActionCommand());
                }
            }
        };

        JButton[] niz = new JButton[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
            niz[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            niz[i].addActionListener(listener);

            p1.add(niz[i]);
        }

        p2.add(txtLabela, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mojOkvir.add(p2);
        mojOkvir.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        forPetlja objekatPrikaziGUI = new forPetlja();
        objekatPrikaziGUI.prikaziGUI();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the if with a for loop"? How is the if block not working? Also, why do you even have an if block -- where are you adding an ActionListener to anything but a JButton? And finally, where is your own for loop code attempt. This would help us to better understand your problem.

Comment: One issue is that your JButton array is being declared as a ***local*** variable within the `prikaziGUI()` method. Why not instead make it an instance field within the class?

Comment: I guess my first question is "why?". The way you have it setup is probably among the best ways to achieve the result you seem to want. But if you "really" want to do this, you will need to create a instance array in which to keep all the buttons, so you can loop through them, compare the source of the event with each instance in the array

Comment: Hi, what I mean my replacing the if loop with a fore one, is that I need the same thing to happen once the for loop is implemented instead of the if one. 
The block is working perfectly but it seems that my teacher will not accept this solution.
Also I'm quite new to Java and am still figuring out how to do things.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot for the input. I have implemented the for loop and it seems to work, but I am receiving a lot of errors. For example:
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)

In the for loop i added an if statement with the following condition (niz[i] == e.getSource()) and changed the label text like this
txtLabela.setText("Kliknut je broj " + e.getActionCommand());
I suspect the problem is in the getSource but I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you have a `NullPointerException` because you've not initialised the array correctly, but I'm guessing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you explain in what way am I initializing the the array? Do I need to code it in a different way than     JButton[] niz = new JButton[9]; ?

Comment: You just need to take `JButton[] niz = new JButton[9];` and move it so it's an instance level field, you can the fill and as you are and should be able to access from anyway within the class